# Three js - the best way to draw text and line

Tags: three.js

after gone through three.js docs, I found it is quite hard to draw line with stroke width, and text.

For the line with stroke width I have to draw an rectange and adjust it to look likes a thick line

For the text, there only two option, one is using font loader, which I found it very hard to handle the promise of font loader, and it become slower if I have so many text.

But if I use canvas to draw the text then use sprite to add that canvas, then I got my texts keep rotates whenever I rotate my camera

so it is 2018, is there any way to make life more easier with three js.

Thanks all

my code to create a thick curve line

```
function curveLine(start, mid, end, width) {
    var curveLine = new THREE.Shape();
    curveLine.moveTo(start.x, start.y + width);
    curveLine.quadraticCurveTo(mid.x, mid.y + width, end.x, end.y + width);
    curveLine.lineTo(end.x, end.y);
    curveLine.quadraticCurveTo(mid.x, mid.y, start.x, start.y);
    curveLine.lineTo(start.x, start.y);
    return curveLine;
}
var line = curveLine({x:0,y:0}, {x:120,y:80}, {x:240,y:0}, 20);
var lineGeo = new THREE.ExtrudeGeometry(line, extrudeSettings);
var lineMesh = new THREE.Mesh(lineGeo, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 'red'}));
scene.add(lineMesh);
```

And this my code to draw text, current using canvas to draws

```
function text2D(text, params) {
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    canvas.width = params.radius * 4;
    canvas.height = params.radius * 2;
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    context.font = '20px Verdana';

    var metrics = context.measureText(text);
    var textWidth = metrics.width;
    context.fillStyle = params.color;
    context.fillText(text, (canvas.width - textWidth) / 2, params.radius);
    var texture = new THREE.Texture(canvas);
    texture.needsUpdate = true;

    var spriteMaterial = new THREE.SpriteMaterial({map: texture});
    var sprite = new THREE.Sprite(spriteMaterial);
    sprite.scale.set(canvas.width, canvas.height, 1);
    return sprite;
}
```

and then whenever i rotate the camera, the text keep face the camera. is there any way to prevent that

Cheers all

Comment: About line width, have a look at this example: https://threejs.org/examples/?q=line#webgl_lines_fat

Comment: Asking "What is the best...?" has the potential to draw opinionated answers. ([`What types of questions should I avoid asking?`](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)) There are many ways to approach the problem you're describing, from defining your own line stroke character set, to drawing the canvas texture to a plane (not a sprite). I recommend you re-word your question to address a problem you're having implementing a particular method (like why using font loader is slow), rather than casting a broad net to fish for alternate solutions.